# What's the best practice of two microservice using share entity?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

Hope you are fine and doing well.

I am a newbie with the implementation of Spring Microservice. I have a case that would need your advice, what's the best practice of communicating two microservice applications which use the same entity or any entity that has a relationship.
**Ex:** I have two applications service as below:

- department-service
- student-service

In **student-service** has a reference **department_id** of department entity which deployed on a separate application.

What should I do for this case?

- create two entities for both application and map @OneToOne relationship?
- create only an entity for each service(department-service(department enity) & student-service(student entity) call rest-client and make relationship level database?

**NOTE:** this table is stored in the same database.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you keep the concerns separate. Let your student service only persist what is tightly coupled to student related entity & similar for department. When it comes to relationships between the tables, let database level constraint and policies act on your behalf. For e.g. A primary key check (Master record check) before you insert data in child table. Spring data JPA will work as is fetching fields from both the tables once you build the project